# Class 'App\Menu' not found (View: D:\xampp\htdocs\mieaceh\resources\views\cart.blade.php)

Tags: php, laravel

Here is my Cart.blade.php view

```
<div class="cart">
   @if (Cart::count() > 0)
   <div class="cart-title">
       <h5> There are {{ Cart::count() }} item(s) in your cart! </h5>
   </div>
   <div class="cart-table">
       <table class="table">
           @foreach (Cart::content() as $item)
           <tbody>
               <tr>
                   <td>
                       <a href="{{ route('shop.show', $item->model->slug) }}">
                           <img src="img\mie1.png" alt="" style="width: 7rem;">
                       </a>
                   </td>
                   <td>
                       <a href="{{ route('shop.show', $item->model->slug) }}">
                           <t style="font-weight: bold;"> {{ $item->model->name }} </t>
                           <br>
                           <d style="color: #acacac;"> varians of this menu the customer chose </d>
                       </a>
                   </td>
```

My web.php

```
 Route::get('/cart', [App\Http\Controllers\CartController::class, 'index'])->name('cart.index');

 Route::post('/cart', [App\Http\Controllers\CartController::class, 'store'])->name('cart.store');
```

Cart controller:

```
 namespace App\Http\Controllers;

 use App\Models\Menu;
 use Illuminate\Http\Request;
 use Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\Facades\Cart;

 class CartController extends Controller
 {
/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function index()
{
    return view('cart');
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{
    Cart::add($request->id, $request->name, 1, $request->price)
        ->associate('App\Menu');

    return redirect()->route('cart.index')->with('success_message', 'Item was added to your cart!');
}

 }
```

When I run, I get this error:

Error
Class 'App\Menu' not found (View: D:\xampp\htdocs\mieaceh\resources\views\cart.blade.php)

I've tried adding ->associate('App\Models\Menu') in the CartController store but still it won't do anything.

Comment: Pls post the code of your Cart model and what are you trying to do by `associate('App\Models\Menu')`

Comment: I am using a cart package from gloudemans/shoppingcart and I'm trying to show the items to the cart. For the associate('App\Models\Menu'), I was trying to associate to my Menu models.

Here is the code to my Menu models:
class Menu extends Model
{
    public function getRouteKeyName()
    {
        return 'slug'; // db column name
    }
}

Comment: you are imported `use App\Models\Menu;`, is it a spell mistake

Comment: I've tried removing the use App\Models\Menu but still nothing changes

Comment: Are you having a `use App\Menu;` statement or any reference to `App\Menu`  in your cart.blade.php

Comment: i've search for that statement in my cart.blade.php but there's nothing

Comment: Try running `php artisan view:clear` to clear the compiled views in case you had `App\Menu` in the view at some point in time and compiled view still has it

Comment: I still get the same error as before

Comment: somewhere in `cart.blade.php` you have a reference to `Menu`

Comment: I've solved the problem, it wasn't in the cart.blade.php but the ->associate('App\Menu'); in the CartController should be ->associate('App\Models\Menu');

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem, it wasn't in the cart.blade.php but the CartController should be like this:

```
  Cart::add($request->id, $request->name, 1, $request->price)
        ->associate('App\Models\Menu');
```